# How to get a flask end point with user selected variables?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am building a web page to show all member account information in a data table. So I made a "members" end point with GET method for this.

The web page have 2 selection fields to choose a region and member type to filter out members that display in the data table.

The members end point is like this

```
@members.route('/members/<int:region_id> <string:member_type>',
               defaults={'page': 1})
def members(page, region_id=0, member_type='basic'):
    member_accounts = MemberModel.query
    .filter_by(region_id=region_id)\
    .filter_by(member_type=member_type)\
    .paginate(page, 25, True)

    return render_template('members.html', member_accounts=member_accounts，
                           region_choices=region_choices,
                           type_choices=type_choices)
    // region_choices and type_choices are dict type data
```

So, the default url is domain/members/0%20basic, which showing members from region 0 and type is basic.

In members.html, I made 2 selection fields for filtering data. Also has a script to make GET request to the end point with selected variables by clicking submit button.

```js
<script>
    function GetFilteredMembers(){
        var regions = document.getElementById("filter-region");
        var region_selected = regions.options[regions.selectedIndex].value

        var mem_types = document.getElementById("filter-mem-type");
        var mem_type_selected = mem_types.options[mem_types.selectedIndex].value

        var Url = "domain/members/" + region_selected + "%20" + mem_type_selected;

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

```html
<select id="filter-region">
    {% for value, text in region_choices.items() %}
    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="filter-mem-type">
    {% for value, text in mem_type_choices.items() %}
    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<input class="btn -light" type="submit" onclick="GetFilteredMembers()">Submit</input>
```

When I select region_id to 1 and member_type to 'admin', then click the submit button. I expect the website will direct to my desired url (domain/members/1%20admin). But this is fail to direct to my desired url. How can I do such filter function properly?

Does constructing a GET request url by javascript a preferred method to do this?
cause I have to hard code the domain in the javascript. Should I build another end point for filtering?

**Update**

modified end point to '/member/'

```
added request.get.args('region_id')
added request.get.args('member_type')
```

Also modified the url in javascript as,

```
'var params = "?" + "region_id=" + region_id_selected + "&member_type=" + mem_type_selected";'
```

and

```
'var Url = "/members/" + params;'
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use query filter, so instead `/members/<int:region_id> <string:member_type>` use just `/member/`. Then just catch filter arguments like this: `region_id = request.args.get('region_id', default=None, type=int)` and  `member_type = request.args.get('member_type', default=None, type=str) `

Comment: Example query: `/member?region_id=1&member_type='test'`

Comment: Then you can construct filtering like this: `member_accounts = MemberModel.query`; `if region_id:  member_accounts = member_accounts.filter_by(region_id=region_id)` etc.

Comment: There is also another way. You can capture whole arguments and pass to `filter_by`. `all_args = request.args.lists()` `MemberModel.query.filter_by(**all_args)`, because `filter_by` can also take keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much@needtobe,
Things seems going in good direction now,
I have updated the GET request url and modified the end point.

But the GET request script seems not working since I did not see request in console. Are there any problem with my script? I am very new a javascript

Comment: Remove last backslash from Url variable. It should be `'var Url = "/members" + params;'`

Comment: Also just `@members.route('/members',
               defaults={'page': 1})`